# How to get metadata from audio files with React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, expo

I'm creating a simple project that is a Music Player and I wanted to know how to get information from the mp3 audio file, such as the album cover.

I'm using expo-media-library to get files from the device with Expo's SDK 49, TypeScript and Android.

Can someone help me please.

I tried using some external libs for this and the result was that it wouldn't compile.